# How to switch players in a list using python?

Tags: python, list

The code I am currently using,

```
if p == players[1]:
    p = players[2]
elif p == players[2]:
    p = players[3]
elif p == players[3]:
    p = players[4]
elif p == players[4]:
    p = players[5]
else:
    # et cetera
```

`p` holds the current player. Everyone playing is in a list called `players`. I did this once with a `modulo` but now I can't remember how.

Comment: Instead of setting the variable to the player, set the variable to the player index. Then you can simply increment the variable modulo len(players)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to use modulo is correct, here is one way to approcah it:

```
def swap_players(ndx):
    return players[(ndx+1) % len(players)]

players = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for n in range(10):
    p = swap_players(n)
    print(p)
```

output:

```
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
```

Answer (score 1):

Use index if the next player is i+1 th player, as follows.

```
i = players.index(p)
p = players[i+1]
```

Comment: just add if statement for the last element